# How to get clean pagination URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, pagination

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/

I'm referring this URL to add pagination to my app but I'm unable to get a clean URL.
URL I get: localhost:8000/?page=2
URL I want: localhost:8000/page/2

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                            {% if queryset.has_next %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- end col -->
            </div><!-- end row -->
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('page/<int:pageno>/', views.index, name='index'), #This path was added just for testing purpose. so that I can hit the URL: website.com/page/3
```

]

**views.py**

```
def index(request, pageno=1):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 2)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)

    try:
        paginted_query = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginted_query = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginted_query = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'queryset':paginted_query,          
        'page_request_var':page_request_var 
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

By doing this I can access clean URL but pagination is not working. It keeps showing me the same landing page on page 2 and doesn't paginate further.

Comment: Please could you share your view code? You need to ensure that you are using the page number passed in from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

get url without query string

```
request.build_absolute_uri(request.path)
```

Comment: I have updated the code blocks. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your template, that any links within your pagination section use the new url format, rather than the url with a query string.

E.g. rather than:

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

Something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'your-url-name' page_obj.previous_page_number %}">previous</a>
```

You also need to ensure in your view, that you are using the page number passed in from the URL.

I hope this is helpful. If not, please could you share your view code and the relevant parts of the template?

Comment: I have updated the code blocks. please take a look at it.